# Cannot set property innerText

Tags: javascript, html, innertext

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="plm.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<h1 id="element">number</h1>
<button onclick="bruh()">Add Num</button>

    </body>



</html>
```

js

```
let nr = 0
let change = document.getElementById("element")
function bruh(){
    nr = nr + 1
 change.innerText = nr
}
```

I get this error "plm.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')

I know that if I write for example
`document.getElementById(element).innerText = nr`  it will work but when I have used replit to write code it worked with putting it in a variable but on vscode is not the same

Comment: `change` is not defined when your script runs, because at the time the element wasn't in the DOM. Move the `script` tag to the end of the `body`.

Comment: Or use [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)

Comment: Move this line `let change = document.getElementById("element")` inside the bruh() and make it first statement of function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that this line:

```
   let change = document.getElementById("element")
```

... is being called before the #element h1 is in the DOM.

A quick fix would be to move this line inside the click callback as I have shown below.

A probably better fix would be defer the execution of your script until a time when you know the element is in the dom, for example:  [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Other options as the commenters have pointed out include using the [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attribute or moving the `<script>` tag to just before the closing `</body>` tag.

```js
let nr = 0
function bruh(){
   let change = document.getElementById("element")
    nr = nr + 1
 change.innerText = nr
}
```

```html
<h1 id="element">number</h1>
<button onclick="bruh()">Add Num</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript file is running before it can access the DOM.

Change this:

```
<script src="plm.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="plm.js" defer></script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer